# PayFlow Pro error -104 "Unexpected transaction state"

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I develop for a credit card processing application that works with PayFlow Pro (among other processors). One of our customers is seeing a "Unexpected transaction state" result when submitting an authorization to PayFlow Pro.

I've found the result listed in the developer docs [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/fraud-protection/#result-values-for-communications-errors), but it does not provide any information as to the cause or how to fix it. Is there anywhere that I can find more information on this issue? PayPal doesn't seem to provide a way to contact them directly regarding development questions, and just points me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the customer had entered the wrong URL for the PayflowPro gateway. It should be "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com" not "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com".

Comment: The URL should actually be "pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com", prepending "https://" caused the -104 error for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PayFlowPro guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf) there is a communication result value with this error code (-104). Check the firewall status in the user computer, is the most common issue.